# Grouping elements (text boxes, buttons, check boxes) on a form in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am working on creating an access form to help my coworkers easily enter information into our SQL server. Here’s the thing- the form has a ton of elements (titles, text boxes, buttons, check boxes, and pretty much everything) and the elements show up and hide dynamically (depending on the choices the user makes as they progress down the form). However, it is going to take forever to code so many

```
example.visible = false or example.visible = true
```

The real question is, is there a way to group elements together so I can just say something like

```
groupOfElements.visible = true or false
```

I think this should be really basic but I am struggling. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks again!

Comment: You can use prefixes, i.e. all controls which belong to foo start with `foo_` (as a label). On the other hand you could also use the `tag` attribute, though I think not all have that. As a third choice you could put the grouped controls into arrays and iterate over them.

Comment: Or you could look here ;) [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661751/grouping-controls-together-on-an-access-form]

Answer (score 0):

I would simply go with a Tab Control option. This way you can combine all information related to each other and dump them in one tab, some other information in another tab etc. So based on the level of access or what information needs to be hidden, you can simply hide the tab using

```
TabControlName.Pages(indexOfThePage).Visible = False
```

You can use the Loop method as shown by Roland, but this could be a bit heavy. Hope this answers your question.